# Combine two different PDFs in single Visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, class, pdf, blob

I have used below visualforce code to display two pdf in a single page but in the result, I am getting two different PDFs with two sections with iframe.

Is it possible to combine these two PDFs in single PDF ?

mainPage

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
    <apex:include pageName="POC_PDF1"/>
    <apex:include pageName="POC_PDF2"/>
</apex:page>
```

POC_PDF1

```
<apex:page >
    This is PDF1
</apex:page>
```

POC_PDF2

```
<apex:page Controller="xyzController">
    <iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,{!pdf}" height="1000px" width="100%"/>
</apex:page>
```

Apex code :

```
public class xyzController {

   public xyzController(ApexPages.StandardController controller){}

   public ContentVersion conVersion {
       get {
           conVersion = [SELECT VersionData, FileType FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocument.Title = 'PDF_081108' AND IsLatest = true];
           return conVersion;
       }
       private set;
   }

   public String pdf {
       get {
           return EncodingUtil.base64encode(conVersion.VersionData);
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Added based on comments**

You need not use `iframe`. Instead you can return the `url` based on `ContentVerionId` and render image/pdf:

pdf2 page:

```
<apex:page controller="poc" renderAs="pdf" >
    <div style="background:red;color:white;">
        This is PDF page 2
    </div>
    <img style="width:600px" src="{!pdfImgUrl}" />
</apex:page>
```

its apex controller:

```
public ContentVersion conVersion {
    get {
        conVersion = [SELECT Id, VersionData, FileType FROM ContentVersion WHERE ContentDocument.Title = 'PDF_081108' AND IsLatest = true];
        return conVersion;
    }
    private set;
}

public String pdfImgUrl {
    get {
        return '/sfc/servlet.shepherd/version/renditionDownload?rendition=ORIGINAL_Jpg&versionId='+conVersion.Id;
    }
}
```

---

**OLD ANSWER**

`iframe` will not work as it creates totally separate `DOM`s. You should use [apex:include](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_include.htm) which will:

> The entire page subtree is injected into the Visualforce DOM at the
>   point of reference and the scope of the included page is maintained.

You can try with 2 options:

**OPTION 1: Join 2 pages and then render as PDF**

MainPage.vfp:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" >
    <apex:include pageName="POC_pdf1"/>
    <apex:include pageName="POC_pdf2"/>
</apex:page>
```

POC_pdf1.vfp:

```
<apex:page  >
    <div style="background:blue;color:white;">
        This is PDF page 1
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

POC_pdf2.vfp:

```
<apex:page  >
    <div style="background:red;color:white;">
        This is PDF page 2
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

**OPTION 2: Create 2 separate PDFs and join them in main page:**

MainPage.vfp:

```
<apex:page >
    <apex:include pageName="POC_pdf1"/>
    <apex:include pageName="POC_pdf2"/>
</apex:page>
```

POC_pdf1.vfp:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" >
    <div style="background:blue;color:white;">
        This is PDF page 1
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

POC_pdf2.vfp:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" >
    <div style="background:red;color:white;">
        This is PDF page 2
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97970/discussion-between-nail-david-and-salesforce-sas).

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Visualforce's PDF rendering library is super-old and you are unlikely to be able to accomplish this goal of merging one dynamically created PDF with one static PDF. The underlying library (Flying Saucer) does have a merge functionality but it is not exposed in any way to Apex/VF so we can't access it.

Conga Composer (paid, uses an external system) does have the ability to run a document merge that stitches multiple PDFs together.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I used an alternate option like displayed two PDFs in a single page with two different iframe. :)